# Use buffer between std::string::end() and std::string::capacity()

Tags: c++, string

Suppose capacity of the string is larger than its size.

Can I use (read/write) buffer between `std::string::end()` and `std::string::capacity()`?

UPD. I am asking **not** about changing trailing `\0` on `end()` position itself.

Comment: Small string optimization may cause problems here.

Comment: Can? Yes. Should? No.

Comment: You can write to this space with `.append()`, of course. And once you've written there, you can read it back. Obviously you have to start with writing, can't read uninitialized data. But this obviously changes `.end()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this if you want to maintain `std::string`'s invariant. There are several ways to get to the data from `std::string` itself but none of them let you legal access that "dead space".  `std::string::operator[]` is only valid for `[0, size()]` so you can't use that.  `std::string::at` is only valid for `[0, size() - 1]` so you can't use that either.  You could get a pointer to the data using `data()/c_str()` but like `operator[]` it is only legal to access `[0, size()]`.

The only method that you can legally use to get a pointer to the entire buffer is to use `&string_var[0]` and then you can write to any index in `[&string_var[0], &string_var[0] + capacity())`.  This can cause issues though.  at `string[size()]` we are guaranteed to have a null terminator and if you overwrite that you'll break std::strings invariant which is undefined behavior and all bets are off.  We also don't have any guarantee that anything you put in that space will stay there.  Since you shouldn't be playing in that space `std::string` is allowed to do anything it wants in there.  It could use it as a buffer for things itself and may overwrite your data, or assume what is there is what it put there and then you've broken it's invariant again.

Long story short: yes you can, but you really really shouldn't.

Comment: I don't think this is formally correct. This assumes `capacity` is in fact the size of a single contiguous buffer starting at `&[0]`, but the only guarantee made by the standard is that you won't have an (observable) reallocation if you never grow the string beyond that capacity. A sufficiently evil (but legal) SSO implementation may have that capacity _before_ `[0]`, and move the content of the string back when appending characters. Within SSO limits this is still O(1).

Comment: @MSalters The standard guarantees `data` returns a pointer where `*(data() + [0, size()])` is valid and `push_back` is guaranteed amortized constant and if had to shift the string back to move into the extra capacity it wouldn't be.

Comment: For an SSO implementation within the small-string limit, that would be O(`sizeof(std::string)`) so O(1). Longer strings are another matter, but the hypothetical SSO implementation only does this when it's using the internal buffer.

Comment: @MSalters Why would it be `O(sizeof(std::string)) so O(1)`.  It needs to copy N characters, and N scales with the size of the string if it is 1, 5, 15 or 1000.

Comment: You're missing the small-string optimization part. The 1000 character string won't use the SSO path. With SSO, there's a non-heap `char buf[FIXED]` inside `std::string`, with `FIXED < sizeof(std::string)` obviously.

Comment: @MSalters I get that.  How is push back on that O(1) as it copies everything in the buffer back one so it can fit the new character.  That would be an O(N) operation.

Comment: You may want to brush up on big-O notation; it describes an upper bound as N goes to infinity. But as N goes to infinity, we don't use the evil SSO optimization anymore.

Comment: @MSalters I don't think the Standard uses _big-O_ notation. It simply uses the term _(time) complexity_. For example, Wikipedia defines _complexity_ as the _amount of resources required for running an algorithm_. In case of _time complexity_, I would dare to translate it into _amount of operations_. Constant complexity then requires a _constant number of operations_, which would not be satisfied with your propsed string shifting in an SSO buffer. In that case, the nubmer of operations would grow proportionally with _n_ (string lenght) and that would imply _linear complexity_.

Comment: @MSalters On Wikipedia, note the difference between [Complexity as a function of input size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity#Complexity_as_a_function_of_input_size) and [Asymptotic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity#Asymptotic_complexity). I believe the C++ Standard refers to the former one. However, in the context of this discussion, one might argue about the meaning of the term _amortized constant time_.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, the element at `s[s.size()]` for a `std::string` `s` is guaranteed to be 0.

The behaviour on writing anything other than 0 to that element, and writing anything to any location after that element is *undefined*.

The rules prior to C++11 were a little different, due to the fact that a NUL terminator was not *required* to be present (although `c_str()` had to yield a buffer containing one), and the string data didn't have to be contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

If you will write directly in the buffer then there will be undefined behavior because the corresponding object will be unable to update its data members.

Comment: What objects with data members are there in a `std::string` data buffer (assuming we're not in the small string optimization case)?

Comment: @MaxLanghof The obejct of the type std::string that holds the buffer. For example you can overwrite the terminating zero. In this case for example the member function compare will yield a wrong result.

Comment: @MaxLanghof No, it is valid also for allocated buffers. For example what about the member function size()? It will not be updated.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but "overwriting the terminating zero" is different from "unable to update its data members". It seems like you're trying to just express "you might break invariants", but I (evidently) have a hard time extracting that from your answer. Do whatever you want with that data point, just trying to help.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Invariants are supported by data members of a class.

Answer (score -1):

Those aren't comparable quantities - `end()` is an iterator, but `capacity()` is a size.

Assuming that you meant to write "between `end()` and `begin() + capacity()`", then that's undefined behaviour.  In particular, many (most?) implementations store a NUL char after the string's content, to make `c_str()` trivial.  Overwriting that would certainly break code.

Comment: Taking that thought a step further... externally manipulating the memory owned and managed by an object could very easily break that objects internal invariants (like the one Toby mentioned:  some implementations may proactively maintain NUL termination... or maybe not... maybe it's only "on demand" when c_str() is called).  It's a violation of encapsulation, and presumes intimate knowledge of the object's privates.  Maintenance nightmare, adversely impacts portability, and easy to wander into UB-land.

Comment: then how about `end()+1` till `begin() + capacity()` I think even without the null it cannot be done without being implementation dependent

Comment: It's still UB, so there's little else we can say about it, really.

Comment: An implementation may very well assume _all_ characters past `end` are `\0`, so it doesn't need to fix up nul-termination after a `.push_back()`. This makes sense from an optimization viewpoint, it's faster to zero one region than to repeatedly zero one element.